# How to describe the status of the products in German?

Tags: english-to-german

In English we use *arrive* to inform our followers that a new version of our recently launched product is available.

How could I buld in German some kind of sentences like following?

> Product 3.0 has now arrived and ready to purchase.
>
> Google has launched a new messaging App.
>
> New version of our hottest theme "Clear Blog" has been released.

(Answers can be in German, because I can now understand German but not write very well.)

Comment: Needn*t it be (1) "and *is* ready to" and (3) "*The* new version"? Shall the sloppy formulation be translated, too? And what did the dictionary tell you? We don't do translation service.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the type of your product and its usual point of sales (a physical shop, an online shop, retail, industrial...)

> Jetzt erhältlich: unser neues Superprodukt X
>
> Ab morgen im Handel: unser neues Superprodukt X
>
> Jetzt für Sie auf Lager: unser neues Superprodukt X
>
> Frisch eingetroffen: die ersten Orangen der Saison
>
> Unsere neuen Schnürsenkel - Bestellen Sie gleich!
>
> Jetzt upgraden! Version 3 unserer Software hat viel weniger Macken als Version 2!
>
> Firma X hat ihr neues Produkt Y auf den Markt gebracht.
>
> Der neue Wein ist fertig! Jetzt einschenken und genießen!
>
> Der neue Opel Minus hat gerade das Werk verlassen und steht für Probefahrten bereit.
>
> Endlich! Version 2 unserer Software steht zum Download bereit.
>
> Direkt von der Drehbank: unsere neuen Schrauben mit parallelem Links- und Rechtsgewinde.

Answer (score 1):

- Version 3.0 unseres Produkts ist fertig und jetzt für [Sie|dich] erhältlich.
- More formal: Google veröffentlichte einen neuen Messenger. (I don't think there's a proper translation for "messaging app".)
- Less formal: Wir haben eine neue Version unseres heißen Styles "Clear Blog" hochgeladen.

The phrases "has arrived", "was launched" and "got released" all mean exactly the same, so it's difficult to translated them with different words. The question is if it should should sound formal or informal. If informal who's the target group? For teens you would rather use "Denglish" terms, for older people you would try to translate more term, even if the translation is not very common. For "tweens" you would use a mix of both: more English terms, but addressing people with "Sie" instead of "du".

Comment: 1. "Product has arrived" heißt für mich, dass es angekommen ist; etwas was ein Händler berichtet, nicht der Produzent ("ist fertig"). 2. "Google hat eine neue Messenger-App veröffentlicht". Ohne *App* könnte es auch eine Applikation sein. *Benachrichtigungsdienst* wäre eine saubere Übersetzung, wenn man unbedingt will. 3. *Hottest* heißt *heißesten*, nicht *heißen* und *released* *veröffentlicht*, nicht *hochgeladen*.

Comment: @userunknown: 1. Im Englischen wird "has arrived" aber tatsächlich auch synonym mit "ist fertig" verwendet. Suche beispielsweise in Google nach "episode has arrived" und "version has arrived". Es gibt zwar in der Tat Beispiele, wo es um eine physische Lieferung geht, aber eben auch viele, wo Hersteller über neue Produktversionen o.ä., die jetzt auf ihrer eigenen Webseite zum Download bereitstehen, berichten. Im Deutschen wird "ist angekommen" tatsächlich nicht in diesem Sinn verwendet, aber bei "ist [jetzt] da" könnte es schon wieder anders aussehen.

Comment: @userunknown: "Benachrichtigungsdienst" sehe ich als Fehlübersetzung; darunter würde ich z.B. eine App verstehen, die mich auf aktuelle Ereignisse hinweist (mich also darüber benachrichtigt). Von einer Messenger-App wird man freilich auch über eingegangene Nachrichten benachrichtigt, aber da ist die Benachrichtigung ja eher Beiwerk und die Kernaufgabe ist das zielgerichtete versenden und empfangen von *Nachrichten*.

Comment: @userunknown, 1. Bereits beantwortet. 2. "Benachrichtigungsdienst" ist doch Unsinn. 3. Im deutschen Werbesprech würde man hier schlichtweg nicht den Superlativ verwenden. Man würde hier nicht "veröffentlicht" sagen. Hochgeladen ("für dich hochgeladen" wäre vielleicht noch besser gewesen) ist eine adäquate Übersetzung für das, was OP überbringen will.

Answer (score 1):

> Product 3.0 has now arrived and ready to purchase.
>
> Google has launched a new messaging App.
>
> New version of our hottest theme "Clear Blog" has been released.

**Product 3.0 ist jetzt erschienen und steht zum Kauf bereit.**

**Google hat eine neue Kommunikationsanwendung veröffentlicht.**

**Eine neue Version unseres beliebtesten Themse "Clear Blog" ist jetzt raus.**

Each of the above is just one way of expressing this.